# cannot convert pdf file with php shell_exec

Tags: php, linux, pdf, shell-exec, imagemagick-convert

I'm having a problem converting a pdf to png, but only when the pdf file has more than one page.

this is what I have:

```
shell_exec("convert -density 600 -quality 100 ".$filepath."/".$filename.$extension." ".$filepath."/".$filename.".png");
```

The funny part is that it works if the pdf has one page and it also works if I run it on the terminal even if it is a multi page pdf.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any problem in your code, except if there is any white space or any special character in the `$filename` or `$pathname`, so you must use [escapeshellarg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).

```
$filepath = escapeshellarg( $filepath.'/'.$filename.$extension );
$outfile  = escapeshellarg( $filepath.'/'.$filename.'.png' );
shell_exec( "convert -density 600 -quality 100 $filepath  $outfile" );
```

Can you share with us what you get in the logs, so we can have an idea about what's wrong.

Comment: in which log should I search